# Unity not working since nvdia graphic driver installed

Tags: unity

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. My computer has the below graphic card:

```
jatin@jatin-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760]
```

I do not have NVidia graphic card installed. Given that I have to program on NVidia Cuda, I installed its drivers and setup from [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/) (atleast so that I could compile the programs and run it on aws). For some reason since I have installed it, my unity has broken.

i.e. Only the desktop is shown without all the panels, launcher bar etc. I have tried every solution on the net since a day and have been unsuccessful (reinstall unity, `ccms` and enabling Unity plugin etc etc). I am a Ubuntu novice, but I think installing nvidia graphic driver might have done something weird.

Can someone please help on how to get my unity working well. (If I run ubuntu in gnome fallback mode, it runs perfectly well)

PS: I do not know if the below is helpful, but I found it to be weird:

On doing `setsid unity`, it shows this:

```
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

Moreover, when I enable Unity Plugin by doing `ccms`. It gets enabled but on restarting ccms, it gets unselected again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extremely weird but it worked. I tried multiple solutions mentioned in other similar questions and restarted a zillion times.

Ultimately in trying different things, I made a new user and logged in to that User. Surprisingly Unity worked well with that User. I logged out and logged in back to my account and Unity started working well.

Truly Weird.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a compiz problem to me more than a driver installation. However if you haven't yet check if there's any graphic driver suggested for you to update in 'Software and Update'->'Additional Drivers'. sudo apt-get update might help to see the latest.

check if ubuntu unity plugin check box is enabled in ccsm. Also try to reset all compiz settings to see if it goes to default.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

unity --reset-icons &disown
```

Restart then.

Comment: I cant access Software & Update from UI. On opening it from `sudo software-properties-gtk` it doesn't suggest any thing. For `ccsm` as I said, it is unchecked, but after checking it and then restartign `ccsm` again removes the check status.
About the above 2 commands, I tried them and no change.

Comment: I forgot to mention but you could also re-install unity from scratch using command line, it works most of the times. But you already fixed it :)

Comment: Ha I did that a couple of times. But it gave no new result. I do not know what clicked but its working now :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new user user did not help for me. So, I reset compiz using

```
rm ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/dconf -rf
```

And after a few flashes unity launch bar and other features were back. But graphics driver is back to original i.e. Intel